# Pass a 'drag and dropped' file to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to access an uploaded file in php. I have two ways a user can upload the file. One can either drag and drop, or click to upload. I'm using ajax to pass the data to php. The way I'm accessing the file in JQuery is

```
new FormData($('#uploadform')[0])
```

Then in php I did `print_r($_FILES)`. When the user clicks to upload, it prints out the way it should. But when the user drags and drops the file, it prints out the following:

```
Array
(
    [img] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

I also tried (for the drag and drop)

```
evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
```

And I got a completely empty array.

How can I pass a 'drag and dropped' image to php?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('#uploadform').on('change', function(evt) {

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      context: document.body,
      data: formData,
      type: "POST",
      timeout: 15000,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // Perform something upon success
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        // Perform something upon error
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#lbl').on('dragover', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#lbl').on('drop', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    // Also tried:
    // var formData = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];

    $.ajax({
      url: $('#uploadform').attr("action"),
      context: document.body,
      data: formData,
      type: "POST",
      timeout: 15000,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        // Perform something upon success
      },
      error: function(jqXHR) {
        // Perform something upon error
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="uploadform">
  <input id="openFile" name="img" type="file" />
  <label for="openFile" name="lblImage" id="lbl"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, I can highly recommend using [blueimp's jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for this job. Implementing this in a way that works across all (major) browsers is a pain.

---

If you insist on doing this yourself, the following steps are necessary:

1. Cancel `dragover` **and** `dragenter` events (`preventDefault` + `stopPropagation`)
2. Get the data on `drop`

   ```
   $('#uploadform').on('drop', function (ev) {
     if (ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer && ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       ev.stopPropagation();
       upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
     }
   });
   ```
3. Upload the files via XHR

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
   for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) {
     formData.append(file.name, file);
   }

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', '/upload.php', true);
   xhr.onload = onUploadCompleted;
   xhr.send(formData);
   ```
4. Handle files uploaded via XHR differently in the PHP backend

   That means you have to satisfy 3 ways of uploading files:

   - HTML Form + file input
   - XHR multipart upload
   - XHR non-multipart upload

   This might be complicated to write yourself! ([Example from the jQuery-File-Upload source](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php#L1054))

Comment: Can you show me a JSFiddle please? Also, why can't I use ajax?

Comment: A JSFiddle for jQuery File Upload? The [demo page of the project](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) has more than enough demos, and example code (also for PHP!) is included with the download.

Comment: _"Also, why can't I use ajax?"_: in the Frontend, conceptually speaking "AJAX" and "using XHTMLHttpRequest" are the same thing. You upload your file not by switching to a different site with a POST request, but by sending it "in the background" via an `XHTMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Oh. I thought you were telling me to switch over to xhr, and not use ajax.  Can you show me a JSFiddle of fix you showed me

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc8vjew6/1/ - for the PHP side of things, read point 4 of my answer. I really recommend using the mentioned plugin for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP $_FILES array will get values from all form elements of type "file".

To debug your script, stick a line of JavaScript/jQuery that does an alert() function and reveals the value of the element with id "openfile".  Place this in an event trigger when the form submits.

It may be that this drag-and-drop feature isn't setting the value of that file form field.  If not, then we'll have to find some other way to achieve that drag-and-drop functionality or get the file to PHP.

Comment: I already checked. JavaScript is getting the file. Also, I think this should be a comment. This isn't an answer.

Comment: What is error "4" in that $_FILES array?  Maybe permissions or the file name/path is in an invalid format or something like that?  It looks like the drag-and-drop is handling things slightly differently than the native HTML input.  Do you have access to the source of this drag-and-drop widget?  Or can you replace it?

Comment: Yes and Yes to your last questions

Comment: Would you upload the source for the drag-and-drop widget or is it hundreds of lines long?

Comment: I gave you everything I have. It's in the JSFIddle

Comment: Ok, so it's something in that AJAX call that isn't working.  (AJAX can be a bear to debug sometimes because it's so silent.)  So we know that the drag-and-drop is successfully setting the file input value.  And we know the server is receiving nothing.  And we see the JavaScript submitting the form successfully.  Where did this JavaScript code come from?  Do we know that it works someplace else?  When in doubt, sometimes it helps for us to break down the bad code and have it perform something simpler so we can see that it's doing something.

Comment: Ok, let's try the following (temporarily) to help us find the bug.  Let's not have the drag-and-drop do any submitting.  Let's merely have the drop-and-drop fill in the value in that file form element.  So in the drop event, if we can see the correct file name with an alert() function, then just update the other DOM element with that value (it should be writable).  And comment out any other JavaScript code for now.  And then manually click the button on the form and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem.
It's not trivial to debug such behavior, but try to check PHP ini setting *upload_max_filesize* - if it less than sum of all filesizes, than PHP will not accept all files and will print just empty array.